# Angular 2+ variable hoisting?

Tags: javascript, angular, hoisting

How does Angular resolve all it's variables regardless of where there placed in a component?

For example in Vanilla JS

```
console.log(a) // undefined
let a = 'Hello;
```

Angular component

```
ngOnInit(){
this.example()
}

example(){
console.log(this.a) // Hello
}

a = 'Hello'
```

I'm aware that this is bad practice and the compiler will complain about that placement of the variable but none the less I am curious how Angular achieves this, or whether it's not an Angular specific behaviour?

Comment: Your code is too zoomed. This piece of code is inside a class, so `a` is not a variable, but a property of your controller class. Properties don't need to be declared before the methods, although the typescript linter will complain about this placement just for coding style reasons.

Comment: Ahhh this makes perfect sense! I'd accept this is an answer if you want to provide it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an Angular behavior. Actually the piece of code that you provided is inside a class, and the `a` is not a variable, actually it's a property.

JavaScript (and Typescript) doesn't requires properties to be declared before methods (neither constructor), since it's just a declaration that will be used futurely when this class will be instantiated.

Although `tslint` may warn you about the placement of it after methods, it's just a coding style concern.

You may translate a class to a traditional function constructor:

```
class Car {
  make = 'default';

  drive() {
     /* ... */
  }

  model = 'foo'
}
```

can be wrote as (and is converted to when using some polyfill on [browsers that doesn't support ES6 Class](https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-class)):

```
var Car = function() {
  this.make = 'default';
  this.model = 'foo';
}

Car.prototype.drive = function() {
  /* ... */
}
```

Note that in the second case, the properties are defined inside the constructor, so it will always run before the method be called.